# Azure mobile service invokeApi not working from cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services(AzMS) in VisualStudio JS-Apache Cordova project where I call a AzMS's custom API to insert user data in storage.  This very same code I have previously used in a VS  web app  javascript and there it is working fine. 
However here in the cordova project, I get an "unexpected connection failure" error when calling invokeApi.  When I try from VS  web app, it works fine, which means the custom API service code is good.

Here is my js client code:

```
  azmsClient.login(oAuthProvider).done(function (results) {
       console.log("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
       var theUserAuthId = results.userId;

        azmsClient.invokeApi('Users/insert', {
               method: 'POST',
                body: { userAuthId: theUserAuthId }
         }).done(function (response) {
                //.... success code
            }, 
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + err.request.responseText);
                //.... error handling
            }); 

  }, 
  function (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err.request.responseText);
    //.... error handling
  });
```

In the console log, the first log ("You are now logged in as: "..) gets logged,  after that the error - unexpected connection failure.
And my azure custom Api code -

```
var logger = require('../api/logUtils.js').logger;

exports.register = function(api){
  api.post('insert', insertUser);
};

/******************************************************************
* @param request
* @param response
*******************************************************************/
function insertUser(request, response){
  var user = request.user;
  var iM = "api.User.insertUser-";
  logger.info( iM + ' called: - ' , request, response, user);
  // Data validation
  if ( user.level === 'anonymous' ) {
    logger.error( iM + 'Anonymous User' );
    response.send(500, { error: "Anonymous user." });
  }

  user.getIdentities({
    success: function (identities) {
        var req = require('request');

        var userId = user.userId.split(':')[1];
        var theProvdr = user.userId.split(':')[0];
        var reqParams;

        logger.info(iM + ': calling getOAuthUserDetails for Identities: - ' , identities);
        try {
            reqParams = getOAuthUserDetails(userId, identities);
        }
        catch(err){
            logger.error(iM + ': getOAuthUserDetails  - ' , err);
            response.send(500, { error: err.message });
            return;
        }

        req.get(reqParams, function (err, resp, body) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(iM + ': Error calling provider: ', err);
                    response.send(500, { error: 'Error calling Authentication provider' });
                    return;
                }

                if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
                    logger.error(iM + ': Provider call did not return success: ', resp.statusCode);
                    response.send(500, { error: 'Provider call did not return success: ' + resp.statusCode });
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    logger.info(iM + ': success: got User Details body ', body);
                    var theAppUser = oAuthUser_To_appUser(theProvdr, JSON.parse(body));

                    addUser(theAppUser, user, {
                        success: function(userAlreadyExist, userEnt){
                            logger.info( iM + ': addUser: success', userEnt);
                            response.send(200, getAppUserEnt(userEnt));
                        },
                        error: function(err){
                            logger.error( iM + ': Error in addUser: ', err);
                            response.send(500, { error: err.message });
                        }
                    });

                } catch (err) {
                    logger.info(iM + ': Error parsing response: ', err);
                    response.send(500, { error: err.message });
                }
            });
    },
    error: function(err){
        logger.info(iM + ': error on calling getIdentities: - ' , err);
        response.send(500, { error: err.message });
    }
});
```

In the azure service logs, I see no entry logged from the custom api's user.insert function when running from the cordova project, which means the api is got getting called. Like said before, when calling from VS web project, the log records look all good. 
(this is somewhat similar to the issue asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669302/android-azure-invokeapi-getting-a-null-pointer-exception), but not exactly the same.)
I am unable to figure out why its happening so; any idea?

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you find solution to this?

Comment: no, I didn't find any solution. Because i hadn't gone too far into my development that time, I simply moved from JS-Apache Cordova visual studio project to empty web project in vs, linked the needed js file for cordova hybrid app along with required azure mobile services client js. In normal VS web project, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on a device, emulator, or Ripple.  If its Ripple, you have to change the Cross Domain Proxy to 'disabled'.  I had similar issues and this seemed to help.